# Passing a variable from one page to another in php to dynamically populate Facebook open tags

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to dynamically populate data in Facebook open tags. For this, I need to pass a variable from my controller file to a file which is outside the CI model. How to do this?

```
public function index()

{ 



   $data['clients'] = $this->qua_model->list_clients();

   $data['clientst'] = $this->qua_model->list_clientst();

   $id = $this->uri->segment(3);

  //GET RECORD BY ID
   $data['result']=$this->qua_model->get_record_by_id($id);
  // print_r($data['result']);


  $data['url']=  urlencode(base_url().'intermediate.php?data=$result');


  // print_r($data['url']);
  // return;


    //echo $data['url'];
    //exit();


   //$data['url'] = base_url().'Testimonial';
   $this->load->view("header",$data);   

   $this->load->view("testimonial",$data);

   $this->load->view("footer"); 

}
```

The above code is the index function of my controller. I want to pass the variable $result to intermediate.php page.

Below is the intermediate.php page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
<!--<meta property="fb:app_id" content="535219850163370" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="meta site name"/>
-->
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.quanutrition.com/Dotcom/new/"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="title"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://quanutrition.com/Dotcom/new//admin/assets/uploads/clients_image/shikhar-dhawan-759.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="My description"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            function Redirect() {
               window.location="http://www.quanutrition.com/Dotcom/new/"; 
            }
         //-->
    </script>

</head>

;
<body onload="Redirect()" >



</body>
</html>
```

Below is the view page where I am setting the session.
$clients is the variable that contains the array.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;
print_r ($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

Now in the other page I am doing this.

```
<?php
  session_start();  
  print_r ($_SESSION);
  $var = $_SESSION['clients'];
  echo $var;
  exit();

?>
```

It is throwing this error - Undefined index: clients.
What am I doing wrong?

This is how a single data in my array in $clients look like

> Array ( [clients] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [client_id] => 1 [name] => Shikhar Dhawan [image] => shikhar-dhawan-759.jpg [video] => [content1] =>
>   "Nutrition plays a key role in my recovery and performance. Using Sports Gene testing and advance nutritional blood biochemistry helps me. Eating with a plan gets more scientific and result oriented this way."

Comment: $result contains an array of data.

Comment: you can [edit] your question if you want to add details.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` in php. See http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php Basically all you do is: start session, put data into session variable and retrieve it on the other page using $_SESSION['var_name']

Comment: I am actually new to this. Should I start the session in the controller?

Comment: Should I store the the variable in session like this?

<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['myValue']=$result;
?>

Comment: And in the intermediate.php  page -

<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['myValue'];
?>

Comment: Should it be like this? @floGalen

Comment: yes basically thats it. I'll post an answer to it :) hold on a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Passing data using $_SESSION in PHP

> Sessions follow a simple workflow. When a session is started, PHP will either retrieve an existing session using the ID passed (usually from a session cookie) or if no session is passed it will create a new session. PHP will populate the $_SESSION superglobal with any session data after the session has started.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Every time you want to store or retrieve data from your session you need to open the session. `session_start();`

So you need to use this in your controler.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```

at the very top. This will start your session and now you can simply store your variables/data in the session you just started. To do so:

`$_SESSION['var_name'] = "value";`

or

`$_SESSION['foo'] = bar;`

On your next page you start all over again with:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```

at the very top. An then you simply call the variable:

`$new_page_var = $_SESSION['foo']; // contains now 'bar'`

If you don't need the variable anymore you can follow this by:

`unset($_SESSION['foo']);`

and the variable will be deleted.

Once you're done and no session is needed anymore you also can detroy the session using: `session_destroy();` - This will delete the session and all the stored data in there!

Hope this helps, cheers :)

---

With your example here:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;
print_r ($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

You're missing $clients variable! Look here:

```
<?php
session_start();
$clients=array("foo", "bar");
$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;
print_r ($_SESSION);
exit();
?>
```

Cheers

---

### More detailed solution

```
<?php
session_start();
$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->client_id = 1;
$object1->name = 'Shikhar Dhawan';
$object1->content1 = 'Some content';

$object2 = new stdClass();
$object2->client_id = 2;
$object2->name = 'Florian Foo';
$object2->content1 = 'Bar some content';

$clients=array($object1, $object2);

$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;

foreach ($_SESSION['clients'] as $client) {
    echo $client->name ." wrote:".$client->content1."\n";
}

exit();
?>
```

Which will output:

```
Shikhar Dhawan wrote:Some content
Florian Foo wrote:Bar some content
```

See here: https://ideone.com/CYDcVa

Cheers

Comment: This sounds easy. I just have this one doubt. $result contains array of data. So is there any particular way of sending the variable containing array of data or it will work if I only send the variable $result?

Comment: Yep php supports arrays in sessions! See here: https://web.archive.org/web/20080707052007/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7

Comment: Yes I am doing exactly that. Instead of setting the session in the controller, I have set the session in my view page where $clients contain all the data I need. I printed the variable and it's showing all the data. See my edit.

Comment: No I didn't use any session_destroy() or unset(). 
And I brought $clients first as you suggested -  $clients=$_SESSION['clients'];
But still it's throwing the same error.

Comment: Have a look at my edit, not `$clients=$_SESSION['clients'];`! Before you can pass a variable into the session it must exist in the first place. So before you do `$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;` you need to create `$clients`. To do so: `$clients=array("foo", "bar");` and then pass it into the session using `$_SESSION['clients']=$clients;`. Cheers  Edit: see here: https://ideone.com/QgJp06

Comment: Yes I did that. And the error is no more. So how can I get the entire data which I am getting in my view page?
Right now in my second page I am getting this - 
 [clients] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar ) )
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am seeing my entire array of data on doing print_r ($_SESSION); in my view page. I need the same data in my second page.

Comment: In your second page start the session with `session_start();` and then do e.g. `echo $_SESSION['clients'][0];` which will display `foo`

Comment: If I replace $client with "foo" and "bar", it is replacing the data in my array and getting passed in the second page successfully. See my recent edit. I have showed you how a single data in my array looks like. I need to pass that in the second page. Thanks.

Comment: And all the data in my array is dynamic. It's in key value format.

Comment: Thank you that was a lot clearer. Now see the data is constantly getting added. So I can't go on defining object1, object2, object3. Because just like the one I showed you there are hundreds of data. So it is obviously not possible to mention all of them individually. So what should I do about that?

Comment: Ok, this was just an example. Don't you have already the $result and that was all you needed to pass over to your next site?

Comment: I have $client which has everything. But when I have passing it blank array is getting passed. In your example you have mentioned static data in the values. I need to pass the dynamic data. My $client contains all the data. But when I am passing it, I am getting blank array.

Comment: See and check if your $client is maybe empty before you pass it. Just do a `print_r($clients);` right before you pass it into the session. Once you have a data filled $clients in the session it should pass all the data without any trouble. So check and see if $clients is filled with data right before you pass it into the session and then check on the new page again if it is still there and holds all the data in it!

Comment: I did check that. In the first page I did print_r ($_SESSION); It is showing all the data in $client.

Comment: Check the following: try on the new page and see if `isset($_SESSION['clients']);` is **true** and further you need to check if your server is set up correct in order to use the session. Check and see if your harddisk has space available on the server. But I assume this will be the case. Then check the `php.ini` if sessions are allowed and especially session cookies. And at last check and see where php is storing the sessions, probably in `tmp` and make sure php can write there. Other than that, please post the code you're using so I can follow this up and check and see if something is missing

Comment: You might also want to check if `memory_limit` in your php.ini is big enough. If you've a lot of data to store you need to raise the limit maybe

Comment: Yeah it is working fine. I can access the data from another page. Thanks a lot.

Comment: hey just needed to know one more thing. How will I print the data from my session in the meta tag? I need to print only a single data. Say for example I need to print the value of name stored in the session in <meta property="og:title" content="title"/> in the content. How can I do that?

Comment: `<meta property="some property" content="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>"/>`  @SayantanMitra